# how can centering tooltip in each div

Tags: html, css, tooltip

there is 4 div with different width! try to put tooltip in center of each div! but i can't do this! also i want put this tooltip in bottom of div and rotate it

how can put this tooltip in center each div and rotate it ? http://jsfiddle.net/5vv8hfLo/3/

```css
.div1 {
 background: yellow;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

.div2 {
 background: red;
 width: 260px;
 height: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

.div3 {
 background: blue;
 width: 160px;
 height: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

.div4 {
 background: pink;
 width: 60px;
 height: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 100px;
}


 
.tooltip {
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
}

/* Gap filler */
.tooltip::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
 pointer-events: auto;
}

/* Tooltip */

.tooltip-content {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999;
 width: 120px;
 bottom: 100px;
 left: 165px;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1.4;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: black;
 background: transparent;
 opacity: 0;
 margin: 0 0 20px -120px;
 cursor: default;
 pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.tooltip-content span {
 display: block;
}

.tooltip-text {
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fcd803;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.tooltip-inner {
 font-size: 10px;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
 webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-inner {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* Arrow */

.tooltip-content::after {
 content: '';
 bottom: -20px;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-top-color: #fcd803;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul>
  <span class="tooltip">
   <div class="div1"></div>
   <span class="tooltip-content">
    <span class="tooltip-text">
     <span class="tooltip-inner">
      test1
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
  <span class="tooltip">
   <div class="div2"></div>
   <span class="tooltip-content">
    <span class="tooltip-text">
     <span class="tooltip-inner">
      test2
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
  <span class="tooltip">
   <div class="div3"></div>
   <span class="tooltip-content">
    <span class="tooltip-text">
     <span class="tooltip-inner">
      test3
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
  <span class="tooltip">
   <div class="div4"></div>
   <span class="tooltip-content">
    <span class="tooltip-text">
     <span class="tooltip-inner">
      test4
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I've updated your jsfiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/5vv8hfLo/5/

You need to make some css changes in .tooltip-content:

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto 20px;
```

Instead of defining a fixed left property you need to set left and right to zero, and then set the left and right margin to auto.

For the last block this doesn't work because the width of the tooltip is longer than the block itself.

I'm not sure what you meant by putting it to the bottom of the div and rotating it...

Comment: nice, how about if I want rotate tooltip, it mean when mouse go on div tooltip open from bottom of div ? I know i should change bottom to top but don't know how change arrow direction

Comment: the arrow is right but tooltip-inner is under the arrow

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but I think you could do it by removing "overflow: hidden;" from tooltip-text and then positioning the tooltip-inner absolutely and centering it: http://jsfiddle.net/5vv8hfLo/10/