# How can I position a tooltip in Materialize in the center of a container?

Tags: css, position, tooltip, materialize

I'm using Materialize for a project and I want a tooltip to appear when I hover the mouse on a div. That's working as it should, however, I want to position it in the center of the div and that doesn't seem to be possible. I know I can position it top, right, bottom and left. I've tried to find some kind of CSS class that I can copy and edit but with no luck.

Comment: You should try this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145732/how-can-centering-tooltip-in-each-div

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good solution is to simply wrap your tooltip in a **`<div>`** and then use the Flexbox solution in order to center it.

So, if this is your tooltip and it's enclosed in a **`div`** tag:

`<div class="container">
  <a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">Hover me!</a>>
</div>`

You can try something in the CSS like :

`.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}`